# Is this correct usage/does it sound natural to use "antithetical" like this?

Tags: word-usage

I want to use it in the following way, but since this is a word I've never really used I'm unsure if it's the correct usage or if it sounds natural.

> This would suggest that knowledge of past prices could be used to
>   predict future price movements, **antithetical** to the concept of an
>   unpredictable market.

Comment: I'd just say "contrary" here. "X is antithetical to Y" sounds natural to me. "X-phrase, antithetical to Y-phrase" doesn't, even if its not technically wrong (not sure).

Comment: I totally understand. Even if it's not technically wrong, I dislike sentences that don't sound natural. Cheers for the advice.

Comment: You really need an adverb or equivalent, and 'antithetical' is an adjective. 'Antithetically' sounds rather ridiculous. 'Contrary' works as a common deletion from 'which is contrary' or 'a situation [that is] contrary'.

Comment: If you want to use *antithetical* in your article or whatever you were quoting from, do it like this: This would suggest that knowledge of past prices could be used to predict future price movements, which is antithetical to the concept of an unpredictable market.

Comment: Makes sense, it's part of my thesis which is why I wanted to double check.

Comment: Aren’t the suggestions in Question and Comments all rather weaker than the content deserves?

Is predicting future price movements merely *contrary* or *antithetical*? Does it just act *antithetically*? Isn’t it in fact the very *antithesis* of the concept (ie, *thesis*) of an unpredictable market?